# How to set hover state to show/hide menu items

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

Work in progress on a d3 [navigation menu](https://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/djcc6kxq/5/) :

thatOneGuy suggested I set hover state for level 2 to keep level 2 rect's visible, that way they wont hide after 1 second but I need some help to get started.  How do I set the hover state?

code snippet:

```
lvl2 = svg.selectAll(".lvl2")
                     .data(data2, function (d) { return d.name; });

       gEnter2 = lvl2.enter()
           .append("g")
           .attr("class", "lvl2")
            .style("fill", function (d, i) { return "url(#gradA" + d.id + ")"; })
         .attr("id", function (d, i) { return d.id; })
         .on('mouseenter', lighten)
         .on('mouseleave', darken)
           .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + 0 + ")"; })
           .style("visibility", "hidden");
```

Comment: Any reason you are doing this with d3?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an acceptable alternative:  https://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/3stdk6L6/2/

```
 var tree = d3.layout.tree().nodeSize([70, 40]);
    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function (d) {
            return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH / 2];
        });
```